# Unix : DenyUsers command NOT working on SSH

Tags: unix, config, swap, sshd

I would like to block some users from ssh login. 
I logged in as root and used Vi editor for making changes in sshd_config. 
Command is :    "  vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config  "
I added   " #DenyUsers user1  "  to the sshd_config and then restarted ssh.
However i still can login to ssh with user1. 
How can i block it? 
Do i have to show you the sshd_config parameters? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting what you added:

```
#DenyUsers user1
```

Lines beginning with a `#` would be treated as comments.  In other words, those would be *ignored*.

You need to add

```
DenyUsers user1
```

(without the little `#` at the beginning of the line)